# number of workspaces in Gnome

Tags: gnome, workspaces

I am using CentOS 6.4 with GNOME.

How can I increase/decrease the number of desktop workspaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you try this?

If you right-click the workspace switcher and choose preferences, you can adjust rows and columns from there.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/add-more-workspace-in-fedora-13-a-825426/

Answer (score 9):

Install gnome-tweak-tool (live.gnome.org/GnomeTweakTool). Go to Shell tab on the left. There is "Dynamic workspaces" and workspace number options. Thats the one I use to make such changes on my desktop.

Comment: Verified working on CentOS 7, Gnome Shell v3.25.

Answer (score 4):

With GNOME 42, the number of workspaces is changed in *Settings > Multitasking*.

> [image: screenshot]

By default, the setting is *Dynamic workspaces*. After changing it to *Fixed number of workspaces*, it's possible to change the number of used workspaces.

Answer (score 2):

I found gnome-help (see below), which eventually led to a workspaces discussion that revealed these user-privilege (not sudo/root) command line instructions for setting rows and columns:

to set number of columns (in my case, 3), change final parameter:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize 3
```

to set number of rows (also 3, here), change final parameter:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ vsize 3
```

The difference for rows vs columns is the next-to-last parameter, either hsize (for columns) or vsize (for rows).

---

Breadcrumbs from gnome-help:

> Ubuntu Desktop Guide » Desktop › Applications and windows » Windows and workspaces › Workspaces »

Heading: "What is a workspace, and how will it help me?"

SubHeading: "Change the number of workspaces"

Ubuntu 16.04 / gnome 3

Answer (score 0):

I am using "[Workspace Grid](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/)" extension for this.

It arranges workspaces in a configurable grid. You can modify the grid as you like.